# How to make a list with generators in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm having problems with this problem because i don't know how to make a list with recursivity using generators. The idea is to create a function that receives a generator that generates n numbers and returns a list with those numbers.

This is my code

```
 ;GENERATOR THAT GENERATES "INFINITE NUMBERS OF FIBONACCI"
(define (fib)
  (let ((a 0) (b 1))
    (lambda ()
      (let ((ret a))
        (set! a b)
        (set! b (+ ret b))
        ret))))

;RETURNS A GENERATOR THAT GENERATES NUMBERS OF FIBONACCI UP TO N
(define (taking n g)
 (let ((i 1))
     (lambda ()         
       (if (> i n)      
           #f           
           (begin
             (set! i (+ i 1))
             (g))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definitions are fine! You just need to call them correctly to see it.

```
> (define t (taking 10 (fib)))
> (t)
0
> (t)
1
> (t)
1
> (t)
2
> (t)
3
> (t)
5
>
```

UPDATE

```
(define (generator->list n g)
  (if (= n 0)
      '()
      (cons (g) (generator->list (- n 1) g))))

(generator->list 10 (fib))
```

Comment: Yes but the question is how to make a list with these numbers, for example (0  1 1 2 3 5)

Comment: @BastianMartinez  I have added a generator to list example.

Comment: Last question, how can it be a function that generates a list but only receiving the generator. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Can you ask in another way?

Comment: Of course, the question is: How would a function receive my generator (fib) and generate a list with the generated numbers. Example: (gen->list (fib))  output: (0 1 1 2 3 5 ... n)

Comment: The definition of `generator->list` in the answer shows how.

Answer (score 0):

So something like this:

```
(define (to-list gen)
  (let loop ((l '()))
    (let ((r (gen)))
      (if r
        (loop (cons r l))
        (reverse! l)
      ))))
```

Untested. What this does is build up a list in reverse consing the truthy items. When it gets a falsy item, it stops and returns the reverse of the accumulation list.